# Ubuntu 19.10: EFI boot options gone after deleting Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-partition

I had a working dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10, both on separate SSDs and decided to remove Windows altogether. I use gparted from a live usb to wipe the Windows 10 SSD altogether but in doing so, I seem to have removed the EFI and GRUB partitions for Ubuntu also. Now my BIOS does not show ANY boot options. Is there a way to recover the EFI boot files for Ubuntu?

My Ubuntu install was running in an lvm partition.

I tried using boot-repair recommended fix but ended up with an error. Here is the pastebin URL with 2,400 lines of text from the boot-info file: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nPVcY3NCHm/

Comment: You have mixed up ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 and /boot which must be ext4 if used. Most systems now do not need it as a separate partition, but some with full drive encryption & LVM need a /boot partition.  Your fstab shows /dev/nvme1n1p1 being mounted twice which is not allowed. And mounted as ext4 for ESP and ext4 as /boot. To get grub to correctly install in UEFI boot mode you must have an ESP.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Ubuntu now uses swap file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I realized my partitions were all messed up to begin with and just reinstalled clean again. It seems like installing windows then ubuntu after in separate drives causes Ubuntu to rely on the efi system partitions provided by the Windows install. Correct me if I'm wrong about this! I'm curious to know how dualbooting OS's use the EFI partitions.

Comment: While grub and other distributions let you choose which drive's ESP to use, Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only uses the first ESP it finds, usually the Windows one, which it then shares. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Answer (score 3):

This is why I don't recommend folks put both OS on different drives; if both OS were on the same drive, when you removed Windows 10, Ubuntu and its boot files would still be there.

When you install Ubuntu, it asks which partition OR drive to use to store the boot information; I normally use the first drive, not any partition; just /dev/sda (or equivalent).

Then /home and  \Users end up on the second SSD, so all the data's together and you only need to back up that second drive frequently.

Can /boot/efi and the GRUB files be recovered? Try the free, Open Source app [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/) which has oodles of documentation and can be installed for Windows, Linux, and MacOS X to recover files from lvm and many, many, more filesystems.

I'd suggest downloading one of the LiveCDs from https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd and writing it to a USB flash drive; booting from there, and start your recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the tools, I'm definitely going to utilize them in the future. I've tried using the tools you mentioned but realized it was way too much effort to learn the intricacies of how to recover the files (especially with LVM partitions). I nuked my ubuntu install and reinstalled it without windows. Although I do wonder, since deleting the Windows drive also removed the EFI files for the Ubuntu drive, do dualbooting OS's share EFI files and partitions?

Comment: Yes, they do, which is why I prefer to put the EFI in /dev/sda instead of in /dev/sda1